# Trying to connect to a SQLite database, keep getting no Suitable Driver Found

Tags: java, sqlite

When I call The staement

```
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db");
```

I get a exception saying

> no Suitable Driver Found for jdbc:sqlite:sample.db

The project is running in eclipse on a windows platform.

This is what I did:

1. WENT TO properties-> java build path -> Add external jar
2. added the file sqllite-3-16-1.jar

The code

```
  try {
      // exception goes off here
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db");     
  } catch(Exception e){
            ted=ted+1;      
  } //
```

Comment: Is the *database* on the classpath?

Comment: How did you get that error message if you are not printing the stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the driver class before trying to acquire the connection. Can you try the following:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

This will throw `NoClassDefFoundError` if the driver `jar` is not on the classpath.

Comment: When it exicutes Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); i get a exception saying cause null detail message org.sqlite.JDBC

Comment: I forgot to press apply after I added the sql jar file